# Swift - Load Local File or URL in NSWebView OSX, Not UIWebView

Tags: macos, webview, swift

Ok, so been working on this issue for a while now, trying to load a local HTML file or URL to a web view in Swift for OS X not iOS.

```
@IBOutlet weak var Webview: WebView!

func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application

    var url = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("pageName", ofType: "html"))

    //var url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")

    var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    Webview.loadRequest(request)

}
```

So I know the above works with iOS and UIKit but it does not work in OS X it gives the error Webview does not have a member named loadRequest and it does not seem to have any methods for loading a URL any help is appreciated!

Comment: I get the same error message with:

    Webview.mainFrame.loadRequest(request:urlRequest)

Answer (score 7):

You must revise your code this way to request the URL as a string first. This works perfectly in swift without caching assets etc:

```
@IBOutlet var webView: UIWebView!

var urlpath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("index", ofType: "html");

func loadAddressURL(){
    let requesturl = NSURL(string: urlpath!)
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: requesturl)
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    loadAddressURL() //func above

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is related to that I am using WKWebView or if things changed since this was answered, but for me I had to construct NSURL such as this: `let requesturl = NSURL.fileURLWithPath(urlpath!)`

Answer (score 6):

Use `Webview.mainFrame.loadRequest(request)` instead of `Webview.loadRequest(request)`

Answer (score -1):

You have to use it:

```
        objweb.delegate = self
        var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundlePath

        var baseUrl  = NSURL.fileURLWithPath("\(path)")

        let bundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        let pathhtml = bundle.pathForResource("pageName", ofType: "html")
        let content = NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile(pathhtml) as String

        objweb.loadHTMLString(content, baseURL: baseUrl)
        self.view.addSubview(objweb)
```

Comment: This does not work in Swift because stringWithContentsOfFile was deprecated in OSX 10.9