# How to load local html into UIWebView

Tags: ios, swift

I am able to load up an external URL in a UIWebView like so:

```
let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.google.com")
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
webView.loadRequest(request)
```

but how do I load a local html file?

The answer in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25100657/swift-load-local-file-or-url-in-nswebview-osx-not-uiwebview) looked promising but Xcode says NSString.stringWithContentsOfFile() is deprecated.

Comment: It is. Show how you've tried to implement it so we can help fill in the gaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do essentially what you're doing now, just use `NSBundle` to get a URL for your local file, like this:

```
if let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("index", withExtension: "html") {
    webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: url))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Nate Cook. Here is the update to Swift 3

```
    if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "about", withExtension: "html") {
        webView.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(url: url) as URLRequest)
    }
```